# Google has indexed several non-existing pages on my WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, divi

When searched on Google my website (elesztohaz.hu) shows up several non-existent pages that seems to come from a separate website. You can see a few [on this SERP page](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:elesztohaz.hu&client=firefox-b-d&ei=YfZeYc-SBJ7-7_UPkKKNiAM&start=30&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiPx8qXtLjzAhUe_7sIHRBRAzE4FBDy0wN6BAgBEEU&biw=1920&bih=927&dpr=1). These results all lead to a 404 page however but I'm unable to find an answer to how Google indexed them in the first place.
Another, more pressing problem would be that several (main) pages on my site are not getting indexed at all. You can see it on the attached screengrab.[Search Console screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyWWa.png) I double checked everything in WP but haven't found anything amiss. No phantom pages and signs of breach.
The website was built with the Divi builder for Wordpress. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you use any demo content with your theme or plugins? Submit the links to search console for removal if they are that big of a problem for you

Comment: Thank you for the response! No, I didn't use demo content, and thank you, good idea, I'll do that. The bigger problem however is that a several important pages doesn't appear in the SERPs. It might be unrelated to the indexing of non-existing pages however...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using WordPress you can go and check it in the WordPress dashboard, pages section and check the unwanted pages that are ranking in the Search Engine is there or not. If it is there and unwanted then move it to trash. Generate a new sitemap and post it in the Google Search Console.
If the unwanted 404 pages are not on your WordPress dashboard pages section then just copy the link from the search engine, go to Google Search Console and add it to removals. Google will remove that in few days.

Another problem mentioned by you is that several (main) pages on your site are not getting indexed as showing in the search console screengrab.
Kindly note that sometimes it is a false positive. To check if the links that are showing as not indexed are false positive or not. Simply copy the link and in google search, search it like **site: "your link"**. For example: https://elesztohaz.hu/ is the first link that is shown in screenshort as not indexed.
In Google Search, search it like- **site:https://elesztohaz.hu/**
If you are getting the result it is indexed and just a false positive.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive feedback Ajit, much appreciated! Yesterday I resent all non-indexed pages for indexation through search console and several of them got indexed by today so great news on that front. I'll use the link removal method, thank you for the advice!